# I want to write the test cases for this file

Tags: reactjs, redux, jestjs, enzyme

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dJ03.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGUxZ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tf6eF.png)

Here is my test code

```
import React from 'react';
import Notification from '../Notification';
import Enzyme, { shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import * as redux from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from '../../Core/Reducers/index';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';


const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe('Should render initial layout Notification', () => {
  it('renders correctly', () => {
    const prop = true;
    const wrapper = shallow(<Provider store={store}><Notification {...prop} />
    </Provider>
        it('renders correctly', () => {
      const spy = jest.spyOn(redux, 'useSelector');
      spy.mockReturnValue('drafts');

    });

    it('renders correctly', () => {
      const setdraftState = jest.fn();
      jest
        .spyOn(React, 'useState')
        .mockImplementation(draftState => [draftState, setdraftState]);
    });
    it('renders correctly', () => {
      const setVenueState = jest.fn();
      jest
        .spyOn(React, 'useState')
        .mockImplementation(venueState => [venueState, setVenueState]);
    });
    it('renders correctly', () => {
      const setAuditState = jest.fn();
      jest
        .spyOn(React, 'useState')
        .mockImplementation(auditState => [auditState, setAuditState]);
    });
    it('renders correctly', () => {
      const setAdminState = jest.fn();
      jest
        .spyOn(React, 'useState')
        .mockImplementation(adminState => [adminState, setAdminState]);
    });
    it('renders correctly', () => {
      const setAdminStateOM = jest.fn();
      jest
        .spyOn(React, 'useState')
        .mockImplementation(adminStateOM => [adminStateOM, setAdminStateOM]);
    });
    it('renders correctly', () => {
      const setInternalVenueState = jest.fn();
      jest
        .spyOn(React, 'useState')
        .mockImplementation(internalVenueState => [internalVenueState, setInternalVenueState
        ]);
    });
    it('renders correctly', () => {
      const prop = true;
      const wrapper = shallow(<Provider store={store}><Notification  {...prop} />
      </Provider>); expect(wrapper.children().length).toEqual(1);
    });

    it('renders correctly', () => {
      const wrapper = shallow(<Provider store={store}><Notification /></Provider>);
      const openNotificationWithIcon = jest.fn();
      expect(wrapper.instance(openNotificationWithIcon));
    });

    it('Render Notification', () => {
      const notify = renderer.create(<Provider store={store}><Notification /></Provider>);
      let tree = notify.toJSON();
      expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
  });
```

I write some test cases but it's giving me 33.36 test coverage few things as I showed you in the image want to cover I am new in  jest and react I would appreciate If you assist me how can I cover all the test coverage

Comment: You may need to interact with the component's API, i.e. UI and/or props and trigger whatever updates to get the `useEffect` hooks to trigger their callbacks to get the additional code coverage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to test your all condition so your code coverage will be increased. So based on that you need to manage your API's response or your state value based on that you can cover that lines.

Example :

`draftStatus` you need to update status based on your condition and write test cases according to that.

`Add, Delete, Failure etc...`

You can use [react-testing-library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro/) and [react-hooks-testing-library](https://react-hooks-testing-library.com/)
for testing your react component and react hooks.

**Basic Hooks**
Imagine we have a simple hook that we want to test:

```
import { useState, useCallback } from 'react'

export default function useCounter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  const increment = useCallback(() => setCount((x) => x + 1), [])
 
  return { count, increment }
}
```

To test useCounter we need to render it using the renderHook function provided by react-hooks-testing-library:

```
import { renderHook } from '@testing-library/react-hooks'
import useCounter from './useCounter'

test('should use counter', () => {
  const { result } = renderHook(() => useCounter())

  expect(result.current.count).toBe(0)
  expect(typeof result.current.increment).toBe('function')
})
```

Comment: OP asks how to increase code coverage and you only suggest an entirely different testing library?

Comment: @DrewReese Since enzyme is at this point almost unmaintained and testing hooks with it is borderline impossible (shallow does not execute effects), recommending a tool that is actually fit for the job seems like a good idea.
https://www.piotrstaniow.pl/goodbye-enzyme

Comment: I don't disagree, it's why I didn't downvote, but you could perhaps improve your answer's quality by explaining why ditching enzyme is a good idea. My guess is that OP won't understand the impetus for why testing React components the way RTL does is an improvement. In other words, they may still be in the "enzyme mindset" and want to tweak/test internal implementation details. OP doesn't need to test the hooks, just get code coverage over them.

Comment: Update the answer @DrewReese

Comment: @Asifvora to be honest, your initial answer provided a lot more value to OP - it just needs a little explanation to the "why". I added another answer, but it might be useful to bring your code examples back ;)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, `enzyme` and the "shallow" (which does not execute effects) testing mindset are not really a thing any more nowadays. (Enzyme itself has been pretty much dropped by airbnb and is maintained by a single person at this point, often lagging behind on React by months).

I would want to encourage you to look into react-testing-library instead, which will also execute your effects (the fact that they are not executed means you are not testing them - that is what coverage tells you in the end).
Also, it shifts the whole "testing mindset" a lot towards "how would a user interact with this?", so it might make more sense for you to read through their tutorials than just providing a code example here.